# Help on a macro for typing number fields

Tags: math-mode, macros

I defined a math macro to type number fields as follows:

```
\newcommand{\Q}[1][]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}[#1\,]}}
```

Here `\,` is to add some space between the number and the bracket.

With `\Q[\sqrt{2}]`, things works fine. However, with `\Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]`, the `\,` seems to disappear, which differs from directly writing `\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}\,]`.

[image]

I think it is probably because the bracket in `[3]` that causes the problem. I then tried to make `#1` into a separate group by changing it to `{#1}`, but then an error occur:

```
Argument of \@sqrt has an extra }.
```

Why did these happen and how should I properly define this macro?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\Q}[1][]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}[#1\,]}}
% \newcommand{\Q}[1][]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}[{#1}\,]}} %ERROR

\begin{document}
\[
    \Q[\sqrt{2}] \quad \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}\,]
\]
\[
    \Q[\sqrt[3]{2}] \quad \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}\,]
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue stems from the fact that you're using "an optional argument within an optional argument," which screws up the square bracket matching. It is fixed by putting the argument within the outer optional argument within curly brackets (or a group):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\Q}[1][]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}[#1\,]}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \Q[\sqrt{2}] \quad \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}\,]
\]

\[
  \Q[{\sqrt[3]{2}}] \quad \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}\,]
\]

\end{document}
```

---

More specifically, here is what happens when you call `\Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]`: The optional argument is captured between the first pair of `[`...`]`, which is `\sqrt[3`. So

```
\Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]
```

expands to (with the captured argument highlighted with `^`):

```
\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3\,]}{2}]
                       ^^^^^^^
```

So, even though your attempt is to place the space `\,` *after* the square root, it is actually captured within root. `\ensuremath` within math mode expands to its argument untouched:

```
\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3\,]{2}]
```

This clearly shows when viewing the two side-by-side: `\Q[\sqrt[3]{2}] \quad \Q[{\sqrt[3]{2}}]`

[image]

Note how the exponent in the first is shifted to the left (due to `\,`).

Another way of correcting this would be to use [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse)'s `\NewDocumentCommand` - it handles optional arguments with nested square brackets properly:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Q}{o}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}[#1\,]}}
```

I would, however, not include the spacing within the definition as it doesn't look right when, for example, you call `\Q[1]`:

[image]

Instead include your spacing as part of the argument which might/not need it.

Comment: Why can't I add these curly brackets at `#1`?

Comment: @Jinwen: By that time the argument as already been captured, so it would be too late.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, there's a simpler way to define this macro, using `xparse`, as follows:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Q}{o}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}\IfNoValueF{#1}{[#1\,]}}}
```

With this, `\Q[\sqrt[3]{2}]` works as expected. (Though I have no idea why this works while the original one don't)

Comment: The LaTeX 2e-kernel and the package xparse bring along different mechanisms for gathering optional arguments. In principle the LaTeX 2e-kernel just detects the presence of `[` via some `\@ifnextchar`-routine based on `\let` and `\futurelet` and if `[` is present gathers an `[`-delimiter trailed by a `]`-delimited argument whereby the nesting of `[...]` and therefore correctly matching `]`-delimiters against `[`-delimiters is not taken into account. The xparse-mechanism gathers things and hereby keeps track of amounts of non-brace-nested `[` and `]` gathered so far.